# Which pathfinding algorithms can be applied on coloured graphs?

Tags: path-finding

Are there any (well validated) approaches for applying pathfinding algorithms on a graph following specific rules?

To be more specific: I want to introduce a graph with coloured edges. The idea is to apply a well known pathfinding algorithm (such as Dijkstra) on the graph given the rule: "only black and red edges".

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is to apply a well known pathfinding algorithm (such as Dijkstra) on the graph given the rule: "only black and red edges"

Remove all the non-black-and-red edges from the graph first, then run it through any off-the-shelf pathfinding implementation.  Or implement your own, and have it completely ignore the non-black-and-red edges.